# How to handle a day starts from 06:00 to 06:00

Tags: mysql

I need to create a new column based on date , this column called Journey must be calculated from 06:00 of day-1 to 06:00 of day.
This is my Code to give an example. But I want to generalize it for all Dates

```
SELECT DATE AS 'Journey1'
FROM `forcage`
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2021-05-18 06:00:00' AND '2021-05-19 06:00:00'
```

Comment: Your query just filters on a specific timerange, Generalizing it to all dates is just removing the `WHERE` query and I doubht that's what you want. Are you just trying to increase every datetime field by 6 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Just substract 6h and recalculate date

```
select date,DATE(ADDTIME(date,"-6:00:00")) AS journey FROM forcage;
```